# UIDocumentInteractionController not launch

Tags: swift

I want to download media file to my iOS app and open it with UIDocumentInteractionController. I succesfully download it to sandbox, it is in document folder, and full path is something like:

```
//Users/Me/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/A8350F24-987E-4518-AA24-A984343623A3/data/Containers/Data/Application/4382B031-EDA5-47AB-91CD-A3C4106C2EFF/Documents/downloadedFile
```

Then i try to use UIDocumentInteractionController but nothing happen. Please take a look:

In top of class:

var docController:UIDocumentInteractionController!

Then:

```
let fm = FileManager.default
let docsurl = try! fm.url(for:.documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
let myurl = docsurl.appendingPathComponent("downloadedFile")
    self.docController = UIDocumentInteractionController(url: myurl)
```

My path is correct, i can check it by finder. I tried it on real device but still not working.

Comment: If you are downloading the file asynchronously, then you need to open the `UIDocumentInteractionController` once the async request has completed. Otherwise, it will not open the file since it doesn't exist yet. Can you share the code where you are making the request to download the file?

Comment: @Malik this is all my code, and when i put breakpoint before that code is executed i can see in sandbox that file exist.

Comment: try adding an extension to it